# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've got a fresh Visual Studio 2017 installation with a fresh .NET Core 2.0 installation. I've created a .NET Core 2.0 Web project in Visual Studio. Now, when I try to do *almost anything* in that project (try to open site.js, try to add some files to wwwroot, try to open site.css etc) I get this error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

This is a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017, fresh install of .NET Core, and a fresh, untouched project with default settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed it. Duh.